# android cannot resolve symbol R in nested package

Tags: android

I have my primary package `com.my.company` and nested package `com.my.company.utils`. The problem is that if I reference `R` class inside my primary package everythings works fine, but if I reference it inside a class in `com.my.company.utils` I get `cannot resolve symbol R` error. I've cleaned the project and checked for malformed xml - nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you import the R class in your package?

```
import com.my.company.R;
```

Comment: No, I haven't, that's it. Thanks! I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes) Can you please elaborate a bit on why I need to import it?

Comment: Because only single R file is generated for whole application and it is associated with application's package name

Comment: Thanks, how's `R` class accessible inside `com.my.company` package classes if I don't include it explicitly?

Comment: @Maximus R class  is implicitly created in your root package. Therefore you don't need to import it.

Comment: @Simas, yeah, that's during runtime. But studio doesn't complain during development either - how's that achieved?

Comment: @Maximus It's not generated during runtime. It's generated during the build process.

Comment: @Simas, yeah, I meant that it doesn't exist during development but studio doesn't complain about that class - how's that?

Comment: @Maximus it does exist during development. Try messing up one of your xmls and build. You'll get your R class deleted and it will complain anywhere in your application. See the [Build Process documentation](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html) for more details.